No image when booting lastest Armbian or RaspberryPI OS using ultrawide monitor
How can I force a smaller display resolution (if that's the real issue) on boot for minicomputers like RaspberryPI or OrangePI when using RaspberryPI OS or Armbian?
I've been trying to use them on my ultrawide monitor, but I get no image at all. They work only on normal monitors or my TV.
